# Archive page of attributes is giving 404 error and terms not getting added just after creating attribute taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am importing products with global attributes, creating attribute if attribute doesnt already exist. below is the function I am using to create attributes.

```
function process_add_attribute($attribute)
{
    global $wpdb;
//      check_admin_referer( 'woocommerce-add-new_attribute' );

    if (empty($attribute['attribute_type'])) { $attribute['attribute_type'] = 'text';}
    if (empty($attribute['attribute_orderby'])) { $attribute['attribute_orderby'] = 'menu_order';}
    if (empty($attribute['attribute_public'])) { $attribute['attribute_public'] = 0;}

    if ( empty( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) || empty( $attribute['attribute_label'] ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', __( 'Please, provide an attribute name and slug.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    } elseif ( ( $valid_attribute_name = valid_attribute_name( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) && is_wp_error( $valid_attribute_name ) ) {
        return $valid_attribute_name;
    } elseif ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'error', sprintf( __( 'Slug "%s" is already in use. Change it, please.', 'woocommerce' ), sanitize_title( $attribute['attribute_name'] ) ) );
    }

    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies', $attribute );

    do_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', $wpdb->insert_id, $attribute );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
    delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
    //set_transient('wc_attribute_taxonomies');
    return true;
}
```

...

```
foreach(attributes as attribute){
$taxonomy = 'pa_'.
$name = $attribute->name;
$slug = sanitize_title($attribute->name);
$taxonomy = 'pa_'.$slug;
if ( ! taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ) {    process_add_attribute(array('attribute_name' => $slug, 'attribute_label' => $name, 'attribute_type' => 'text', 'attribute_orderby' => 'menu_order', 'attribute_public' => true));}


foreach ($attribute->options as $option) {  wp_insert_term($option,$taxonomy,array('description'=> '','slug' => sanitize_title($option)));}
}
```

two issues here is 
1) when this code runs first time it simply create attributes not terms. when I run this code again then it create terms..
In other words terms only added when attributes is already there. why?

2) I am adding attributes with enable archive. when I visit atribute archive page its give me 404 error. and when I go to edit attribute from admin section and click save button manually then links start working without any error.

this code runs in `scheduled event`.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new attribute (or a new taxonomy -> that's the same object type for WP), you need to flush the permalinks in order to make it work.

You can either visit the `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` page and hit the `Save` button (no change needed) or use the [flush_rewrite_rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) function.

As long as you won't flush the rules, WP will not be able to detect your new taxonomy so you'll always get a 404 error page.